# Laravel Cashier producing corrupt pdf invoice on Fortrabiit

Tags: php, laravel, pdf, fortrabbit

I'm using Laravel Cashier and can produce and download invoices fine in my local environment. The invoices are around 138KB. However, when I try to download the invoice in my Fortrabbit production environment the pdf produced is only 2KB and I cannot open it.

The error I get in Chrome is "Failed to load PDF document" and when I try to open it with OSX Preview the error is:

"The file “Subscription_8_2015 (1).pdf” could not be opened.
It may be damaged or use a file format that Preview doesn’t recognize"

Now, obviously this has something to do with server settings or missing package. Rather than me trawling for hours through these settings does anyone know off the top of their head what could be culprit?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you open the created file with a normal text editor ? There might be some hint in the file about what was going wrong.

Comment: @Marged thank you for the advice. It's full of html. So Laravel Cashier creates an html page and saves it as a pdf. Will investigate further.

Comment: Cashier uses phantomjs to create the pdf (https://github.com/laravel/cashier/blob/bf62f7f7152734ec5e8dde9314254c1fd1d774c0/src/Laravel/Cashier/Invoice.php#L334). The dependencies for this kind of 'headless browser' are not available at the fortrabbit php runtime. I suggest to replace the pdf generation with dompdf: https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it will help if you show us some code. How does your controller look like? How is the output form / pdf file generated?

Start from scratch by simply creating an invoice with a plain "hello" in it and try to create it properly on fortrabbit and see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

Change the file permission of the phantomjs file you need to 744 which will be located in either

```
(app_name)\laravel\cashier\src\Laravel\Cashier\bin\linix-i686
```

or

```
(app_name)\laravel\cashier\src\Laravel\Cashier\bin\linix-i686_64
```